# converting from Eigen::Vector to Eigen::Affine3f

Tags: c++, eigen, point-clouds

I used the code as follows:

```
   Eigen::Vector4f Template_centroid;
   pcl::compute3DCentroid(*Template,Template_centroid);

   Eigen::Vector4f model_centroid;
   pcl::compute3DCentroid(model.cloud,model_centroid);

   // Transformation required to align the centroids
   Eigen::Affine3f transform(Eigen::Affine3d::Identity());
   transform.translate(Template_centroid-model_centroid);
```

but when it compiles the translate, I have got the errors:

```
 error: \u2018INVALID_MATRIX_PRODUCT\u2019 is not a member of \u2018Eigen::internal::static_assertion<false>\u2019
```

Does anyone know how to transform or what is the reason of the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`transform` is a 3D affine transformation, so its `translate` member is expecting a 3D vector while `Template_centroid-model_centroid` is a 4D vectors. You can drop the last homogeneous component (which is 0 I guess), and get a 3D vector using `(...).head<3>()`.

Comment: Hi, I have tried transform = (Template_centroid-model_centroid).head<3>(). But i still got a error :                                                                       /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:290:5: error: incomplete type ‘Eigen::internal::transform_construct_from_matrix<Eigen::Block<const Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_difference_op<float>, const Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, const Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >, 3, 1, false, false>, 2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 1>’ used in nested name specifier

Comment: you're trying to convert a Vector3 to an Affine transform. What does that mean? Either convert it to a `Translation3f` or call .translate(), or directly set the translation part using the translation() accessor.